# Prevent a user from typing a duplicate number into a search bar

Tags: ios, swift

My code seems too long and it's not even complete!

I am trying to avoid a duplicate in a search bar.
I have it working for the first entry only.

Been playing around with this for a while but I'm sure it's more simple than what I seem to be making it.

```
    var search : String = ("1, ")
    let numbers = search.map { String($0) }
    let duplicates = Array(Set(numbers.filter({ (i: String) in numbers.filter({ $0 == i }).count > 1})))
    for item in duplicates
    {
        search = search.replacingOccurrences(of: item, with: "")
    }
    if mainSearchBar.text != search
    {
        mainSearchBar.text = (mainSearchBar.text ?? "") + search
    }
```

The first number entered (with the comma and blank, is a total of 3 characters) doesn't get duplicated when entered on the second occasion which is great.

I want any number already in the search bar to not be duplicated at all.

The above code is the function of button 1.
There are a few buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `UISearchBarDelegate` method that can help you with that. I hope this helps you:

with this method you ensure no duplicated character will be in your new String

```
func removeDuplicates(in searchText: String) -> String {
        var newString = ""
        searchText.forEach { character in
            if !newString.contains(character) {
                newString.append(character)
            }
        }
        return newString
    }
```

And then you have to inherit from UISearchBarDelegate

```
extension **YourControllerName**: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchBar.text = removeDuplicates(in: searchText)

    }
}
```

In order to get this working you must set `mainSearchBar.delegate = self` somewhere in your code. Usually in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to emelagumat, I managed to get it working like this.

```
func removeDuplicates(in searchText: String) -> String
{
    let search : String = (mainSearchBar.text ?? "")
    var newString = search
    searchText.forEach
        {
            character in
        if !newString.contains(searchText)
        {
            newString.append(searchText)
        }
    }
    return newString
}
@objc func button1Tap()
{
    let search : String = ("1, ")
    mainSearchBar.text = removeDuplicates(in: search)
}
```